# IEnumerable return type C# C++

Tags: c#, c++-cli, ienumerable, return-type

I have C# interface with a method  signature like this:

```
IEnumerable<string> Myfun();
```

In C++/CLR what is the data type to receive the returned strings?

I have tried

```
IEnumerable<std::string> ^abc = myObject.Myfun();
```

I get this error: 
error C3225: generic type argument for 'T' cannot be 'std::string', it must be a value type or a handle to a reference type

Comment: Sure. How to do that? ( I only looked to "accept" button o this page.)

Answer (score 5):

Use this:

```
IEnumerable<String^>^ abc = myObject.Myfun();
```

You need to use the `System::String^` as your type, not C++'s `std::string`.

If you need to work with `std::string` to pass to other C++ code, you need to use

```
std::string myCPPstring = marshal_as<std::string>(myDotNetString);
```

Comment: @qqqqq The C# language has aliases for some .NET types. `string` means: `System.String` (C#), `System::String` (C++/CLI).

Answer (score 1):

Been a long time since I've touched C++/CLI, but I think it will be:

```
IEnumerable<String^> ^abc = myObject.Myfun();
```